# i can't connect to facebook with wolfram connector, any help?

Tags: webservices, social-media

Out[23]= ServiceConnect["Facebook", "New"]

In[24]:= ServiceConnect["Facebook"]

During evaluation of In[24]:= HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication::accfail: Failed to obtain OAuth access token for Facebook.

During evaluation of In[24]:= ServiceConnect::token: Could not obtain a request token for the OAuth service Facebook >>

Out[24]= ServiceConnect["Facebook"]

Comment: Please, read the FAQ and format your code properly.